# Select array of html elements using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an array of elements in a table like this:

```
<td><input type="number" min="0" name="value[]" value="22.00"  class="form-control"></td>

<td><input type="number" min="0" name="value[]" value="11.00"  class="form-control"></td>
```

I want to do some validation on these values when I submit.

How can I obtain all the elements with name="value[]"?

I tried `$("[name='value[]']").val();` but this only gives me the first one.

Comment: Iterate `$("[name='value[]']")` object using `.each()` i.e. `$("[name='value[]']").each(function(i, el){ var v = $(el).val(); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a loop like below

```
$("input [name='value[]']").each(function(index,val){
  console.log($(val).val());
});
```

You can see the output on the console.